# Making brick texture same density on all sides

Tags: texturing

I'm having trouble making the texture density the same on all sides, because one of the sides are thinner than the others, what am i doing wrong?[image: you can see the different densities and sides here]

Comment: Watch some videos about UV and UV mapping in Blender. Start with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM&ab_channel=Blender

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeBUfMKKZDo&ab_channel=BlenderGuru this video is also great

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure you applied scaling (select object, CTRL-A -> scale)

[image]

2. use this node setup:

[image]

3. in UV Editing tab: select all vertices with A (right side) -> then choose UV -> Unwrap

[image]

result:

[image]